# Chaum–Pedersen Protocol explanation for dummies. What I'm doing wrong?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, discrete-logarithm

The screenshot from a book with Chaum–Pedersen Protocol description is below.

[image: Chaum–Pedersen Protocol description]

I'm trying to implement it for my own. And I don't get math here.

My assumptions:

1. Discrete Logarythm functions:

[image: Discrete Logarythm]

2. The dot in the formula below is a usual multiplication: 2 • 2 = 4

Examples:

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parameters do not satisfy the assumptions for the protocol.

To have $g$ and $h$ generate groups of prime order $q$ they must belong to such a group.

So $q$ (which in reality must be picked large enough for DL to be hard) must be a prime larger than both $g$ and $h$. So $q$ must be larger than 7919.

Comment: Thanks! You're definitely right. Also, I found the same question with great [explanation](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/99262/chaum-pedersen-protocol).