# Chaum-Pedersen protocol adapted to elliptic curves

Tags: elliptic-curves, zero-knowledge-proofs

Is it possible to adapt the Chaum-Pedersen protocol for using elliptic curves by simply replacing the exponentiation with scalar products?

[image: zk protocol]

For example, if `g` is a point in the curve, then `g^k` is the scalar multiplication `k*g` as defined for elliptic curves. Would that still work?

I took the diagram from [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/99262/chaum-pedersen-protocol).

Update:
In the verification process, there is this: `g^s * y1^c`, which would be like a product of points; as far as I know, point multiplication is not typically defined for elliptic curves. What is the equivalent operation there?

Comment: Yes it would. Similarly for any cyclic group in which the discrete logarithm is hard.

Comment: You'd need to choose the generator point $g$ carefully so that it has order $q$.  Unlike what you'd do in this protocol for the multiplicative group, with elliptic curves you might as well have $q$ as close as possible to the number of points--you wouldn't choose $q$ to be quite a bit smaller than $p$. Also, you might to take care with invalid curve point attacks and subgroup confinement attacks.

Comment: Thank you, I miss that in the verification process; there is this: `g^s * y1^c`. This would be like a product of points; as far as I know, point multiplication is not defined. What is the equivalent operation there?

Comment: In additive notation, exponentiation becomes multiplication, and multiplication becomes addition. So it would be $s*G+c*Y_1$. The two operations are scalar multiplication (a point added to itself many times), and point addition.

Comment: Thanks for that; it is crystal clear and makes full sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the Fiat–Shamir heuristic is applied, the non-interactive version would be:

$Y_1=xG$ and $Y_2=xH$, where $G$ and $H$ are generator points on the curve and $x$ is a scalar.

We intend to prove discrete-log equivalence, along with knowledge of $x$.

We pick a uniformly random scalar $k$, and calculate the challenge $c=H(kG\mathbin\| kH)$, where $H()$ means to hash the input to a scalar value, and $\mathbin\|$ means concatenation.

The proof is $(c,s)$, where $s=k-cx$. This operation should be modulo the order of the group.

Verification: check $c\overset{?}{=} H(sG + cY_1\mathbin\| sH+cY_2)$